# Power BI - Adding Days to a value Conditionally

Tags: sharepoint, powerbi

So, we have a Sharepoint List in Office 365, that is setup simliar to this:

```
First Name|Last Name|Email|HOI Order Date|HOI Received Date|HOI Cleared Date|Appraisal Order Date|Appraisal Received Date|Appraisal Cleared Date|Title Ordered Date|Title Received Date|Title Cleared Date|Flood Cert Ordered Date|Flood Cert Received Date|Flood Cert Required|Flood Insurance Order Date|Flood Insurance Received Date|Flood Insurance Cleared Date|FraudGuard Ordered Date|FraudGuard Received Date|FraudGuard Cleared Date|Lock|Lock Date|Lock Expiration Date|ICD Ordered|ICD Order Date
```

Name and email are just plain text, all Date fields are set to Date/Time in sharepoint, and the 'Yes/Now' fields like `Flood Cert Required` just have a choice of `Yes` or `No`.

But, when we go into Power BI, and link our sharepoint list, which works, we cannot seem to run `DATEDIFF()` functions on any of the date fields, without first creating a measure like:

`HOIC = SUMX('CA Tracking', DATEADD('CA Tracking'[HOI Cleared Date].[Date], 0, DAY))`

That's the only way that something like `DATEADD('CA Tracking'[HOI Order Date].[Date])` doesn't return an error that the column cannot be found.

So, what I want to do here, for example, is reference the value in the row, and return a `Due Date` for the given Categories like `HOI` and `Title` for example.

So, i wrote this, hoping it'd work, which obviously it didn't lol:

```
HOI DUE = 
IF (
    ISBLANK([HOIC]), 
    // Cleared is Blank, check if Received is blank too
    IF (
        ISBLANK([HOIR]), 
        // HOIR is blank, check if HOIO is blank too
        IF (
            ISBLANK([HOIO]), 
            // HOIO is blank, so we'll set it to 3 days after created
            DATEADD('CA Tracking'[Created], 3, DAY), 
            // HOIO is NOT blank, so we'll set it to 3 days after HOIO
            DATEADD('CA Tracking'[HOI Order Date], 3, DAY)
        ), 
        // HOIR isn't blank, so we'll set it to 3 days passed HOIR
        DATEADD('CA Tracking'[HOI Received Date], 3, DAY)
    ), 
    // HOIC isn't blank, so we'll set the due to to the same as HOIC
    DATEADD('CA Tracking'[HOI Cleared Date], 0, DAY)
)
```

Sorry, but when it comes to PowerBI/DAX I'm a bit of a noob. I have already checked:

1. Each date column is set to Date/Time inside of SharePoint and Power BI
2. Each Date Column has a date/time format within Power BI

And yet, anytime that we try to reference the date/time fields, Power BI cannot reference them unless we create a calculated field with thier values instead.

Sorry this was a bit confusing, I hope y'all can help :)

Answer (score 0):

The [DATEADD function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/dateadd-function-dax) is intended to operate on a column of dates, not on specific ones.

Try this instead:

```
HOI DUE =
IF (
    ISBLANK ( [HOIC] ),
    IF (
        ISBLANK ( [HOIR] ),
        IF (
            ISBLANK ( [HOIO] ),
            'CA Tracking'[Created] + 3,
            'CA Tracking'[HOI Order Date] + 3
        ),
        'CA Tracking'[HOI Received Date] + 3
    ),
    'CA Tracking'[HOI Cleared Date]
)
```

Comment: Sadly, this returns the same issue as stated in the question. Those columns, while lthey do exist, DO NOT appear as useable in the function as it returns 'Column not found'. Unless I have to create a mesure like i did for EVERY date/Time column to be able to work on it, i don't see a way to make this work as intended.